# Prove that the trigonometric ratios are equal for a given angle regardless of the length of the arms of the angle.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\ XOY$ be an angle.

Let $\ A$ and $\ a$ be two points on OX. Drop perpendiculars to OY from $\ A$ and $\ a$ that intersect OY at $\ B$ and $\ b$ respectively. It is required to prove that $\frac{AB}{OA} = \frac{ab}{Oa}$. How to proceed?
[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St16W.jpg)
[I found this in a book but I didn't understand it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jO0M.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: People may be hesitant to respond as some may not want to just solve a potential hw problem, but a good place to start would be in looking how to identify what you have as similar triangles. A) what does that mean, B) how can that be true here?

Comment: No, no it is not a homework problem let me  clarify in my next edit

Comment: HW or not, I think the easiest way to tackle this is through looking at the 2 things I listed in A ) and B). Or if you're not in a section focused similar triangles and want to use trig functions, then just looking at the triangle aOb, you can write-down relationships between the angle and the sides (one in particular addresses aO and ab). And if you write that down, and continue to do the same for AOB, then...... maybe you can notice the last step to connect the 2.

Answer (score 0):

Triangles $ OAB, Oab$ are similar due to the fact that $ab$ is *parallel* to $AB$.

Corresponding angle equal. At $(b,B)$ we have right triangles.

So the trig ratios can be defined either with the small triangle or the bigger triangle.

Comment: Can you please further explain how ab being parallel to AB implies that the ΔOab and  ΔOAB are similar?

Comment: When a transversal line cuts 2 parallel lines corresponding angles are equal.

Comment: Does this imply from Thales Basic Proportionality theorem?

Comment: Suggest learn about early Euclid geometry theorems